# Botão submit só atualiza o BD depois de apertar F5

Tags: php

Estou criando um jogo RPG de browser onde o jogador cadastra primeiro e raça e depois é redirecionado para uma página onde escolhe a classe. Ao clicar no botão submit, a raça e os status da raça são salvos no BD e o jogador deveria ser redirecionado em seguida, o problema é que quando eu clico em cadastrar a raça, a página atualiza mas os dados do usuário não são enviados pro BD, apenas quando eu aperto F5 é que os dados são enviados e eu sou redirecionado para a próxima página. Alguém sabe dizer o porque isso acontece?

```
    if ($numPers == 1) {
        header("location:cadastrarclasse.php");
    }elseif($numPers > 1){
        header("location:taverna.php");
    }
    else{
```

Esse código fica acima do head. O else é caso o usuário ainda não tenha cadastrado nada, então ele fica na página de cadastrar raça.

Comment: Bem amigo você precisa colocar um trecho do código onde você acha que está o problema. Assim fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Meu problema é justamente não saber onde está o erro ashuuasuasuashuas. Coloquei a parte onde as páginas são redirecionadas para ajudar a entender a lógica.

Comment: Nesse caso poste uma quantidade maior de linhas.

Answer (score 0):

Header não transfere os dados $_POST ou $_GET entre as páginas PHP, somente define o cabeçalho HTTP e redireciona o usuário. 
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php

Você deveria utilizar um **include**, que transfere o fluxo de execução do seu Script para outro arquivo e retorna depois dele.

```
if ($numPers == 1) {
   include "cadastrarclasse.php";
} else if($numPers > 1) {
   include "taverna.php";
}
```

Problema parecido que você deve estar enfrentando aqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281900/php-header-redirect-with-post-variables